# How do I measure JVM startup time?

Tags: java, jvm

I have an application written in java and I want to know how much time it takes before reaching `static void int main(String args)` and what it is doing at that stage how can I achieve that?

I am aware that microsoft have a tool called MPGO (Manager profile guided optimisation) is there an equivalent for Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple way to measure start-up time from inside Java application:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long vmStartTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();
        System.out.println(currentTime - vmStartTime);
    }
}
```

You may use [JVMTI agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) for tracing VM events like class loading, garbage collection, method compilation etc. Here is a simple agent I've made - [vmtrace](https://github.com/apangin/vmtrace) (and the [compiled dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LUxTf0AV-fN3l5NGgyLVRfQk0/view?usp=sharing) for Windows).

Run `java -agentpath:path\to\vmtrace.dll Main`, and the event trace will be printed to `stderr`:

```
[0.00000] VMTrace started
[0.00182] Dynamic code generated: flush_icache_stub
[0.00187] Dynamic code generated: get_cpu_info_stub
[0.00519] Dynamic code generated: getCPUIDNameInfo_stub
[0.00524] Dynamic code generated: forward exception
[0.00526] Dynamic code generated: call_stub
...
[0.01182] Loading class: java/lang/Object
[0.01198] Loading class: java/lang/String
[0.01206] Loading class: java/io/Serializable
...
[0.05620] VM initialized
[0.05664] Class prepared: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle
[0.05672] Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl
[0.05732] Class prepared: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl
[0.05738] Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$1
[0.05743] Class prepared: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$1
[0.05755] Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$2
[0.05759] Loading class: java/util/function/Function
[0.05768] Class prepared: java/util/function/Function
...
```

Comment: I have tried it out and it does seem to be giving me some nice values, however sometimes the description is missing or malformed i.e. I get things like [0.02056] Dber and [0.031ber . One more strange thing is that I get two VM start messages coming up. Also not all the timestamps are sequential is that due to threading? Lastly there is no last record called [VMTrace ended] which would allow me to calculate the time gap between the last two records.

Comment: @Har Yes, in multithreaded environment output can appear mixed due to concurrency issues. A mutex that surrounds [`trace`](https://github.com/apangin/vmtrace/blob/master/src/vmtrace.c#L25) function should solve the problem. It may be also better to separate agent output from application output - you may specify the file name as an agent argument.

Comment: @Har I've updated `vmtrace` to synchronize output and to log [VM destroyed].

Answer (score 4):

With [java 9](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) you can add `-Xlog:class+init=info:file=trace.log` to trace class initialization (which is the next step after class loading) and then filter for your main class. It's a new [logging feature](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158).

You can also tell it to log everything to see what happens prior to startup, but the amount of events logged would probably distort the results.

In java 8 and lower different VM components have their own logging (often just via printf) and class loading is one that does not include timestamps.

Comment: How do you specify to enable timestamps? I cant find the option for that so far I have -XX:+TraceClassResolution -XX:+TraceClassLoading  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:LogFile=C:\Users\Har\out.txt -XX:+PrintCompilation

Comment: sorry, i misremembered, in 8 you only get timestamps for printcompilation and gc logs (neither of which is useful to determine startup time), not for classloading. I guess those inconsistencies is one of the reasons they unified the logging in 9

Answer (score 3):

One more way to measure the startup time is to use [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html)
which is available since [Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    var processStartTime = ProcessHandle.current().info().startInstant().get();
    System.out.println(currentTimeMillis - processStartTime.toEpochMilli());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jrockit jvm you can add the following flag to understand timings of the jvm starting up

```
-Xverbose:codegen
```

Further details are here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/slow_start.html#wp1083972

**Update 5/9/2016**

Further to our conversations below.  jstat will provide time-based stats regarding the classloader.  A virtual machine id (vmid) must be obtained by executing

```
jps
```

With this id the following can be executed

```
jstat -class {vmid} 1000 10
```

This will provide a snapshot of the classloader every second for ten seconds.

Comment: are these options available in the freely java 8 se version?

Comment: The best features were merged into hotspot.  Look under the debugging heading on the following page to get this information for Java 8 se.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: Look at ciTime or maybe traceClassLoading

Comment: wow thanks alot thats what I am looking for, ill give that a go

Comment: ahh it doesnt give me the time it only says what its loading but doesnt indicate how long it takes to load each module, I get something like:[Loaded java.text.DecimalFormat from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]

Comment: I see what you mean by debugging options: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html theres a debug section there thats really helpful

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: windows, the information with the traceClassloading is what I want but just with the time added on on how long it takes for them to load