# How to list syntax and available tags for -Xlog

Tags: jvm, java-9

OpenJDK 9's new [Unified JVM Logging](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) can filter logs by tags, but the JEP does not provide a list of all available tags. How can I list all available arguments?

Comment: who would want to close this? it's a good question.

Comment: Shameless plug: I wrote [a post about unified logging with `-Xlog`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/unified-logging-with-the-xlog-option/). It's a little gentler than `-Xlog:help`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`java -Xlog:help` prints the argument syntax, including the list of tags available in that particular version, which may change over time.

Note that logging with `-Xlog:<tag>` may not print everything related to that tag since it requires the log message to *only* have that tag. Use `-Xlog:<tag>*` instead to include messages containing multiple tags.

Comment: this might help, in case you have not see it already. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2015-September/014773.html